# common/unified regex for a set of pattern

Tags: python, regex, match

I am trying to do some text processing and was interested to know if I can have a common/unified regex for a certain pattern. The pattern of interest is strings that ends with `{string}_{i}` where `i` is a number, on the second column of `test.csv`. Once the regex is matched, I wish to replace it with `{string}[i]`.

For now the python script works as expected for the strings for which I explicitly mention the regex pattern. I want to have a more generic regex pattern that will match all the strings that have `{string}_{i}` instead of writing a regex for all the patterns (which is not scalable).

###### input test.csv

```
bom_a14 , COMP_NUM_0
bom_a17 , COMP_NUM_2
bom_a27 , COMP_NUM_11
bom_a35 , FUNC_1V8_OLED_OUT_7
bom_a38 , FUNC_1V8_OLED_OUT_9
bom_a39 , FUNC_1V8_OLED_OUT_10
bom_a46 , CAP_4
bom_a47 , CAP_3
bom_a48 , CAP_6
```

###### test.py

```
import csv
import re

# Match the values in the first column of the second file with the first file's data
with open('test.csv', 'r') as file2:
    reader = csv.reader(file2)
    for row in reader:
        row_1=row[1]
        # for matching COMP_NUM_{X}
        match_data = re.match(r'([A-Z]+)_([A-Z]+)_(\d+)',row_1.strip())
        # for matching FUNC_1V8_OLED_OUT_{X}
        match_data2 = re.match(r'([A-Z]+)_([A-Z0-9]+)_([A-Z]+)_([A-Z]+)_(\d+)',row_1.strip())
        # if match found, reformat the data
        if match_data:
            new_row_1 = match_data.group(1) +'_'+ match_data.group(2)+ '[' + match_data.group(3) + ']'
        elif match_data2:
            new_row_1 = match_data2.group(1) +'_'+ match_data2.group(2)+ '_'+ match_data2.group(3)+'_'+ match_data2.group(4)+'[' + match_data2.group(5) + ']'
        else:
            new_row_1 = row_1
        print new_row_1
```

###### output

```
COMP_NUM[0]
COMP_NUM[2]
COMP_NUM[11]
FUNC_1V8_OLED_OUT[7]
FUNC_1V8_OLED_OUT[9]
FUNC_1V8_OLED_OUT[10]
 CAP_4
 CAP_3
 CAP_6
```

###### expected output

```
COMP_NUM[0]
COMP_NUM[2]
COMP_NUM[11]
FUNC_1V8_OLED_OUT[7]
FUNC_1V8_OLED_OUT[9]
FUNC_1V8_OLED_OUT[10]
CAP[4]
CAP[3]
CAP[6]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [`sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) with a single generic *pattern* :

```
with open("test.csv", "r") as file2:
    for row in csv.reader(file2):

        s = re.sub(r"(.+)_(\d+)$", r"\1[\2]", row[-1].strip())

        print(s)
```

> Regex : [[*demo*](https://regex101.com/r/yt5s65/1)]

Output :

```
COMP_NUM[0]
COMP_NUM[2]
COMP_NUM[11]
FUNC_1V8_OLED_OUT[7]
FUNC_1V8_OLED_OUT[9]
FUNC_1V8_OLED_OUT[10]
CAP[4]
CAP[3]
CAP[6]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use re.search the regex does not have to fully match a string but only a subpart.
More notice you do not even need to use a csv reader to achieve what you want.

```
import re

data="""bom_a14 , COMP_NUM_0
bom_a17 , COMP_NUM_2
bom_a27 , COMP_NUM_11
bom_a35 , FUNC_1V8_OLED_OUT_7
bom_a38 , FUNC_1V8_OLED_OUT_9
bom_a39 , FUNC_1V8_OLED_OUT_10
bom_a46 , CAP_4
bom_a47 , CAP_3
bom_a48 , CAP_6"""

for line in data.split('\n'):
    match_data = re.search(r'(\w+)_(\d+)',line)
    if match_data:
        g1,g2=match_data.groups()
        print(f"{g1}[{g2}]")
```